# TypeError: URL is not a constructor - react-dev-utils/getPublicUrlOrPath.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, terminal

Just restarted my machine this morning and woke up to this nice error when running *react-scripts start* to get my react site running locally.

```
/blah/blah/node_modules/react-dev-utils/getPublicUrlOrPath.js:52
    const validHomepagePathname = new URL(homepage, stubDomain).pathname;
                                  ^

TypeError: URL is not a constructor
    at getPublicUrlOrPath (/blah/blah/node_modules/react-dev-utils/getPublicUrlOrPath.js:52:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/blah/blah/node_modules/react-scripts/config/paths.js:26:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/blah/blah/node_modules/react-scripts/config/env.js:13:15) 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
npm ERR! errno 1 
npm ERR! blah@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start` 
npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Failed at the blah@0.1.0 start script. 
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

It was working last night but I restarted my machine and it wasn't working in the morning.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

False alarm. Just in case anyone else runs into this, you might be using an old version of Node. I have install Node Version Manager (NVM) on my machine and ran the following command:

```
nvm use v9.5.0
```

now we're back in business!